# Enforce (fix) imports to be fully on a single line

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have the following eslint config:

```
   "object-curly-newline": ["error", {
        "ImportDeclaration": "never",
        "ExportDeclaration": "never"
    }],
```

That transforms:

```
import { 
    something,
    somethingelse, 
} from "../here";
```

to

```
import { something,
    somethingelse, } from "../here";
```

but I'd like to get my import so it goes to a single line. Like so:

```
import { something, somethingelse, } from "../here";
```

Is there a way to do this within "object-curly-newline"? Or can I accomplish it via some other rule? I've tried the various other properties, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Hey Mark, could you find a solution for this? I'm dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this might be related to the `multiline` setting of [object-curly-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len), depending on your settings.

> `"multiline": true` requires line breaks if there are line breaks inside
> properties or between properties. Otherwise, it disallows line breaks.

That is what I noticed in my situation.

[image]

You can see which rule applies before saving, by hovering over the red or yellow underlines. In my case these were shown underneath the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from `object-curly-newline`, which can be configured specifically for named imports using `ImportDeclaration`:

```
{
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", {
        "ObjectExpression": ...,
        "ObjectPattern": ...,
        "ExportDeclaration": ...,
        "ImportDeclaration": "never"
    }]
}
```

As stated [in the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-newline#options):

> `"never"` disallows line breaks after opening and before closing braces